# He doesn't play football "or" tennis. Is it correct?

Tags: neither-nor

As the title says, should I say:

He doesn't play football or tennis.

Or

He doesn't play football nor tennis.

Or "nor" only comes with "neither" ?

And will it be also be correct to say: 
"He doesn't play neither football nor tennis." ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of these are correct:

> ✘ He doesn't play football nor tennis.
>   ✘ He doesn't play neither football nor tennis.

---

However, all of these are fine:

> ✔ He doesn't play football or tennis.
>   ✔ He doesn't play football and he doesn't play tennis.
>   ✔ He plays neither football nor tennis.
>   ✔ He doesn't play football, nor does he play tennis.